# how do you concatenated column value for row in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to create a new column with concatenated values from other columns in each row of my dataframe:

here is my current attempt

```
dataFrame['images/0'] = 'https://img.ssensemedia.com/images/b_white,g_center,f_auto,q_auto:best/' + str(dataFrame['sku']) + '_' + '0' + dataFrame['name']
```

but this is creating a column with values from all of the other rows too. How do I create a new column for each row from the other values of a row? I cant find a definite answer anywhere.

Comment: can you post what your original dataframe looks like?

Comment: `str(dataFrame['sku'])` turns the whole column into one single regular string. If `dataFrame['sku']` contains numerical data, you probably meant `dataFrame['sku'].astype(str)`. If the column already contains strings, just omit the surrounding `str(...)`. Then the broadcasting should work as expected.

Comment: thanks the bottom bottom answer worked. apply is the function I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try with `apply()`:

```
dataFrame['images/0'] = dataFrame.apply(lambda x: f"https://img.ssensemedia.com/images/b_white,g_center,f_auto,q_auto:best/{x['sku']}_0{x['name']}", axis=1)
```

By setting `axis=1` it will pass row by row to `lambda` so you can access individual column values with `x['column_name']`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["test_sku", "test_name"]], columns=["sku", "name"])

df['images0'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'https://img.ssensemedia.com/images/b_white,g_center,f_auto,q_auto:best/' + str(x['sku']) + '_' + '0' + x['name'], axis=1)
```

The output dataframe looks like this:

```
        sku       name                                            images0
0  test_sku  test_name  https://img.ssensemedia.com/images/b_white,g_c...
```